# OpenBSD USB install; how to mount usb and find file sets:

Tags: mount, usb, system-installation, usb-drive, openbsd

During an OpenBSD install from USB, if one has reached the `Pathname to the sets?` prompt and the USB stick is not mounted, how does one find the usb device name, mount the usb drive and direct the installer to the correct files?

In my case the OpenBSD version is 7.3 amd64.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this great post](https://teddit.net/r/openbsd/comments/9xitpz/need_help_with_usb_install/e9uld2t/#c):

1. Start a shell from the installer; type `!` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Identify USB device name; remove the USB and re-insert. Find the `sdx` name, e.g. `sd4`.
3. `cd /dev`
4. `sh MAKEDEV sdx` (e.g. `sd4` from step 2)
5. `mkdir /usb`
6. `mount /dev/sdxa /usb` (e.g. `sd4a` from step 2)
7. `exit` (exits the temporary shell and returns to the OpenBSD installer)
8. `/usb/7.3/amd64` (at `Pathname to the sets?` prompt. Note may be different dependent on OpenBSD version and target architecture; re-start shell and check `/usb` dir if unsure)